# pulling in a variable in the URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, url, variable-names

When I send a campaign the variable 't1CategoryLinkName' doesn't get pulled in and I end up with this link `<a href="https://www.sport.co.uk//?utm_source=`

I've tried setting up a new variable right above it and call it and still doesn't work. Initially,  I thought it might be a problem with the data linking but if I hard code the category bit in the URL with the category name, like shoes, it will work so the issue I can think of is in this syntax

`<a href="https://www.sport.co.uk/%%=v(@t1CategoryLinkName)=%%/?`

Every other variable works as it should.

Do you spot anything wrong with the url Syntax?
Any ideas how could I wrap the variable in a different way?

Thanks!

`<a href="https://www.sport.co.uk/%%=v(@t1CategoryLinkName)=%%/?utm_source=%%=v(@track)=%%&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=test-test&utm_content=%%=v(@track)=%%shop-all" style="font-family:' arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">SHOP<span style="text-transform:uppercase">%%=v(@t1CategoryDisplayName)=%%</span></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
%%[

set @CustomerID = _subscriberkey
set @link = "https://www.sport.co.uk/"
set @t1CategoryLinkName = Lookup("test test","Product Tier 1 Category","CustomerID", @CustomerID)
set @track = [set where your parameter comes from]
set @url = concat(@link,@t1CategoryLinkName,"/?utm_source=",@track,"&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=test-test&utm_content=",@track,"shop-all")

]%%

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@url)=%%" style="font-family:' arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">SHOP<span style="text-transform:uppercase">%%=v(@t1CategoryDisplayName)=%%</span></a>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97416/discussion-on-answer-by-coderage-pulling-in-a-variable-in-the-url).